# How to solve simple linear homogeneous ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple linear ODE giving me a hard time:

$y'''+y=0$

The characteristic equation is

$r^3+1=0$

where we obtain a root of -1 repeated three times. The general solution should therefore equal:

$y=c_1 e^{-x}+c_2 x e^{-x}+c_3x^2e^{-x}$

Unfortunately when I plug this back into the equation it does not reduce to zero. I feel like I am taking the wrong approach. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: $r^3+1$ has three distinct roots.

Comment: Note that you look for roots in $\mathbb{C}$. The equation doesn't have a repeated root at $-1$! It has $3$ distinct roots: $1, \omega, \omega^2$, where $\omega = \exp (\frac{2i\pi}{3})$.

Comment: Hint: $r^3+1=(r+1)(r^2-r+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, the solutions of your characteristic equation are $\{1, \omega, \omega^2 \}$. If you draw them in a plane they form the vertices of a triangle and you can easily see that $\omega^2 = \bar{\omega}$ (this has to be so because your polynomial has real coefficients) so the general solution of your equation is:

$$y(x) = Ae^x + Be^{\omega x} + C e^ {\bar{ \omega} x}$$